# Limit of a sequence inside a set

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $A$ be a bounded set, and let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a convergent sequence, with a limit $L$, such that $a_n\in A$ for all $n$. I want to prove that $\inf{A}\leq L\leq\sup{A}$.

Intuitively, it is clear - since $a_n$ converges, I can find elements arbitrarily close to $L$.

Since $a_n$ is convergent, then for all $\varepsilon > 0$, for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$, for all $n>N$, $|a_n-L| < \varepsilon$. Suppose $L < \inf{A}$. Then let $\varepsilon = \inf{A} - L>0$, and then let $N$ be such that for all $n>N$, $|a_n - L| < \inf{A} - L$.

Then $L-\inf{A} < a_n- L < \inf{A} - L$, and from this, we get that $a_n < \inf{A}$, a contradiction.

Should I care about the left inequality? Is the proof for $\sup{A}$ the same, just flip $|a_n-L|\leftrightarrow |L-a_n|$?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct - essentially what you're saying is "The limit is $\varepsilon$ away from  $\inf A$. My terms are eventually all close to $L$, so in particularly they must be within $\varepsilon$ of it, and therefore far away from $\inf A$". The $\sup$ argument is essentially the same.

You would have used the left inequality if you'd written $|a_{n}-L|$ as $|L-a_{n}|$ (they are the same). I'm confused by your comment at the end - why would you swap those terms round?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seem correct. The left inequality is of no real interrest and should probably be left out in order to improve clarity or beauty.

The proof of the opposite is basically the same. Or you could use the fact that $\sup A = -\inf \{x : -x\in A\}$ and apply your result directly.